# android snackbar - how to test with roboelectric

Tags: android, robolectric, android-snackbar

From [here](http://raptordigital.blogspot.com/search/label/snackbar) we now know that robolectric does not have a shadow object but we can create a custom shadow object for a snackbar.It's ashame they have one for toast but not for snackbar.

I am showing a snackbar in my code when there is no network connection. I'd like to know how can i write a unit test (with robolectric as the test runner) that can verify that a snackbar gets shown when there is no network connection.

Its a little hard because the snackbar is not in xml. So when i declare my actually Activity controller it doesn't have a snackbar at that time.

You know how to test a toast we have `ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast()`   i want one for snackBar

im currently using org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2 and dont see ShadowSnackbar.class available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually explained in the blogpost how to add the ShadowToast class to enable testing.

1. Add the ShadowSnackbar to your test sources;
2. Add the Snackbar class as an instrumented class in your custom Gradle test runner;
3. Add the ShadowSnackbar as a Shadow in your test;

In your app's code, you'll call on the Snackbar when no internet connection is available. Because of the configuration (e.g. intercepting of) the Snackbar as Instrumented class, the Shadow-variant of the class will be used. You'll be able to evaluate the result at that moment.

Comment: I believe this this is not part of robolectric, it was another developer explaining how it can be done, correct ?

Comment: Indeed, it is not a part of Robolectric, and chances are that it might not be included, unless someone contributes it maybe. It seems that to day Android and its support libraries are evolving more quickly than Robolectric. And that "other developer", that's me.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a much [simpler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50860390/1396264)

you can just do:

> ```
> val textView: TextView? = rootView.findSnackbarTextView()
> assertThat(textView, `is`(notNullValue()))
> ```

Implementation:

```
/**
 * @return a TextView if a snackbar is shown anywhere in the view hierarchy.
 *
 * NOTE: calling Snackbar.make() does not create a snackbar. Only calling #show() will create it.
 *
 * If the textView is not-null you can check its text.
 */
fun View.findSnackbarTextView(): TextView? {
  val possibleSnackbarContentLayout = findSnackbarLayout()?.getChildAt(0) as? SnackbarContentLayout
  return possibleSnackbarContentLayout
      ?.getChildAt(0) as? TextView
}

private fun View.findSnackbarLayout(): Snackbar.SnackbarLayout? {
  when (this) {
    is Snackbar.SnackbarLayout -> return this
    !is ViewGroup -> return null
  }
  // otherwise traverse the children

  // the compiler needs an explicit assert that `this` is an instance of ViewGroup
  this as ViewGroup

  (0 until childCount).forEach { i ->
    val possibleSnackbarLayout = getChildAt(i).findSnackbarLayout()
    if (possibleSnackbarLayout != null) return possibleSnackbarLayout
  }
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me, but it was a very simple use case

```
@Implements(Snackbar::class)
class CustomShadowSnackbar {

    companion object {
        val shownSnackbars = mutableListOf<Snackbar>()

        fun Snackbar.getTextMessage(): String {

            val view = (this.view as ViewGroup)
                .children
                .first { it is SnackbarContentLayout } as SnackbarContentLayout

            return view.messageView.text.toString()
        }

        fun clear() {
            shownSnackbars.clear()
        }
    }

    @RealObject
    lateinit var snackbar: Snackbar

    @Implementation
    fun show() {
        shownSnackbars.add(snackbar)
    }

    @Implementation
    fun __constructor__(
        context: Context,
        parent: ViewGroup,
        content: View,
        contentViewCallback: ContentViewCallback) {

        Shadow.invokeConstructor(
            Snackbar::class.java,
            snackbar,
            ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(Context::class.java, context),
            ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(ViewGroup::class.java, parent),
            ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(View::class.java, content),
            ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(ContentViewCallback::class.java, contentViewCallback)
        )
    }
}
```